# SwiftUI LazyVStack with pinned views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

**Context**: I need to pin a view in a ScrollView to the top of the screen when scrolling, so I use a LazyVStack with pinnedViews, set the view I need as Section. All good.

**Issue**: The ScrollView other views might change the content while the view is scrolled to the bottom, when that happens the screen removes all views and doesn't display them back unless I scroll to the top.

**Question**: Is there another way to pin a view to the top? (I tried to use List, but not exactly what I need) Or is possible to make a custom Stack with pinned views?

Comment: Needed minimal reproducible example to debug problem.

Comment: I'm thinking that you want to pin a bunch of items from your scrollview to the top. If so, why not just use two lists - one to show all your pinned views, and right below it, another one. Both of them can be scrollable. Pinned views IMO, are for something like this: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-pinned-views-tutorial

Comment: @technusm1 The ScrollView contains 2 views, then the pinned view, then more views. All works great, but the pinned view is the one that triggers the second part of scrollable views to change. When change happens, all the views(top, pinned, bottom) just disappear, so I have to scroll to the top manually to make them render. I tried to scroll the view to the top before/after the bottom views change, no success. I think is because of the Lazy loading of the LazyVStack...

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer for another post, but it seems like you both are having a similar problem. Download and import TrackableScrollView, and try out the below code. While scrolling, there is a pinned View() which is displayed at the top of the screen.

Link package: https://github.com/maxnatchanon/trackable-scroll-view

Code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUITrackableScrollView //Added
import Combine

struct GameTabView: View {

@State private var scrollViewContentOffset = CGFloat(0) //Added
@State var selectedTab: Int = 0

init() {
UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}

var body: some View {
listView
    .ignoresSafeArea()
}

var listView: some View {
ZStack { //Added
    TrackableScrollView(.vertical, showIndicators: true, contentOffset: $scrollViewContentOffset)  {
        VStack {
            Color.gray.frame(height: 400)
            sectionView
        }
    }
    if(scrollViewContentOffset > 400) {
        VStack {
            headerView
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
}

var sectionView: some View {
Section {
    tabContentView
        .transition(.scale) // FIXED
        .background(Color.blue)
} header: {
    headerView
}
}

private var headerView: some View {
ScrollViewReader { proxy in
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        HStack(spacing: 16) {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    selectedTab = 0
                }
            } label: {
                Text("AAAA")
                    .padding()
            }
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    selectedTab = 1
                }
            } label: {
                Text("BBBB")
                    .padding()
            }
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    selectedTab = 2
                }
            } label: {
                Text("BBBB")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
.background(Color.green)
}

@ViewBuilder private var tabContentView: some View {
switch selectedTab {
case 0:
    DummyScreen(title: "FIRST", color: .red)
case 1:
    DummyScreen(title: "SECOND", color: .green)
case 2:
    DummyScreen(title: "THIRD", color: .blue)
default:
    EmptyView()
}
}
}

struct DummyScreen: View {
let title: String
let color: Color
var body: some View {
VStack {
    ForEach(0..<15, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Text("#\(index): title \(title)")
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .font(.system(size: 30))
                .padding(.vertical, 20)
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
.background(color)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not really clear what the *issue* is, but this code should do what u are asking:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, pinnedViews: .sectionHeaders) {
                Section {
                    ForEach(0..<50) { _ in
                        Text("Helloworld")
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("Header")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, I have done this using a VStack.

```
VStack{ 
    PinnedItems()
    LazyVStack {
        OtherItems()
    } 
}
```

Then Pinned items will not scroll and are permanently attached to the top. And the lazyVStack will still be able to scroll underneath.

Comment: I know what you mean, but the pinned view is not the first top view.
Vstack { 
   View()
   View()
   PinnedView()
   OtherViews
   ...
}

Comment: And I need to remove the Lazy also